# spring-data + neo4j + mongodb conflict?

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, spring-data

I'm going to use both neo4j & mongodb in my system.

Here is my dependency versions:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.neo4j.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.neo4j.version>
    <spring.mongodb.version>1.6.2.RELEASE</spring.mongodb.version>
    <spring.data.common.version>1.5.0.RELEASE</spring.data.common.version>
</properties>
```

and header of my spring config file is :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.5.xsd">
```

When i ran my program,  i met this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 52 in XML document from class path resource [spring-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd; lineNumber: 52; columnNumber: 51; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'repository:repository' to a(n) 'type definition' component
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.RC2.jar:4.0.0.RC2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.RC2.jar:4.0.0.RC2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.RC2.jar:4.0.0.RC2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.RC2.jar:4.0.0.RC2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.RC2.jar:4.0.0.RC2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.RC2.jar:4.0.0.RC2]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) ~[spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) ~[spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1763) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.55]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.7.0_67]
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.7.0_67]
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.55]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.7.0_67]
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.7.0_67]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487) [na:1.7.0_67]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97) [na:1.7.0_67]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328) [na:1.7.0_67]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420) [na:1.7.0_67]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848) [na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322) [na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177) [na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174) [na:1.7.0_67]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_67]
```

this didn't happen when i had only spring-data-neo4j in my system. Can anyone tell me how to solve it? Is it a version conflict problem?

ps: if i remove

```
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.5.xsd"
```

in context.xml header, the exception will come from spring-mongo-1.5.xsd, instead of spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 262 in XML document from class path resource [spring-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.5.xsd; lineNumber: 262; columnNumber: 63; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'repository:auditing-attributes' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
```

Comment: Please add more of the stacktrace and spring-config.xml

Comment: First, i would replace spring-beans-4.0.0.RC2, with 4.0.6 too. But this wouldn't be the reason i think. Could you provide an minimal example project of this on github or somewhere else? There could be a ton of reasons what happend here.

Comment: thanks for replying. i figured it out by removing version numbers from schema xsd in schemaLocation.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i removed the version number of my schema xsd, got it work.

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd
```

Comment: In your context.xml you specified spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd, i guess you were using features which have not been available back in 2.0. spring-neo4j.xsd always refers to the latest version of the xsd as you can see in the last line of https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.schemas